# Deleting all consonants from a string using recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm almost completely new to programming and I try to learn C++. This is the first task where I feel like I hit a wall. I tried to search but because people usually use a loop to solve the problem I could not find anything.

I tried to find a recursive solution to delete all consonants from a string (I think I know how to solve it using loops, but wanted to expand my knowledge on recursion).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int i = 0;
string s("");

string del_cons(string z){
    if(i == (z.length()-1) ){
        s+= z.substr(i);
        return s;
    }
    else if(z[i] == 'a' || z[i] == 'e' || z[i] == 'i' || z[i] == 'o' || z[i] == 'u'){
        i++;
        s+= del_cons(z.substr(i));
        return s;
    }
    else{
        s+= z.substr(i,1); 
        i++;
        s+= del_cons(z.substr(i));
        return s;
    }
}


int main(){
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);

    cout << del_cons(x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles, but when trying it out with a string, I get this error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 3) > this->size() (which is 2)
```

Abgebrochen (Speicherabzug geschrieben)

When playing around with the code, this line seems to be the problem:

```
s+= del_cons(z.substr(i));
```

Could somebody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong? It seems I'm misusing the substr() function, but I don't know how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As for your *recursion* problem... note that your index `i` is *global*, while your recursive calls work on `substr()`ings of the original input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanna learn about recursion and do more 'by hand', it is probably easier to look if there are still consonants existing in the string, possibly using `z.find_first_of(consonants)`, where `consonants` might be a string consisting of all the consonants. If it returns `std::string::npos`, no consonant was found and you can return the input string (stop criterion).
Otherwise you take the consonant out (you now know its position), maybe using `z.substr` and concatenating the substrings before and after the consonant. Then you call your function recursively with the new string.

You could then write a more general function that takes a second string which contains all the characters you want to remove from a string.

Also, it is not good code practice and one of your biggest flaws in the code to use global variables as recursion parameters (what do you do when you have two recursive calls in your function, for example?). You'd also need to reset them when the function finishes or you wanna call it multiple times. In your case, you call your function with a string that has to be processed from the beginning but `i` might already be incremented. You'd rather wanna give `i` as a parameter to indicate on which letter to start or – even better – change the structure of your function. When I write functions recursively, I often think of the stop conditions first: In which cases is there nothing to be done (like an empty string or a string without consonants)? Then I think of what has to be done in the other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I could not resist... C++ is such a beautiful and powerful language if used to its full potential...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline( std::cin, s );
    s.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            s.begin(),
            s.end(),
            [](unsigned char x){
                return std::string( "aeiouAEIOU" ).find( x ) == std::string::npos;
            }
        ),
        s.end()
    );
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I know begin() and end() exist through reading, but haven't seen them yet on my learning materials which is why I did not want to use anything like that. I'm really just trying to wrap my head around recursion. :)

Comment: and seriously, don't be sorry, I was kinda prepared for people to be annoyed at a dumb beginner question like that. You guys probably read tons of them every day.

Comment: @Lotte: I figured as much. It just pains me to see the vicious cycle of people "taking the long route" to solve a problem, posting questions about their problems, and others walking away with the impression of "oh, but C++ *is* a difficult and primitive language if you have to do it that way"... ;-)

Comment: @Lotte: Also, lots of learning material on C++ takes the route of "teaching C first", which I am not alone in considering [a bad idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). I know I didn't help you with your recursion problem, but I felt like a "real C++" solution needed to be among your answers. ;-)

Comment: "Now witness the firepower of this fully armed and operational programming language"

Comment: @user4581301: "Is the Dark Side stronger?" -- "No. No. No. Quicker, easier, more seductive..." :-D

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't resist either

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

std::string del_cons(std::string const & str)
{
    if (!str.size())
        return "";

    if (!std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[0])) ||
        "AEIOUaeiou"s.find(str[0]) != str.npos )
        return str.substr(0, 1) + del_cons(str.substr(1));

    return del_cons(str.substr(1));
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << del_cons(input) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Looks very much like you would program it in a pure functional language - nice.

Comment: It would possibly be a bit more readable if you separated out part of the logic into `bool is_consonant(char c)`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler oh, sorry, i'm prepearing for next years ioccc ;) code edited.